# How to override the default pickle and torch file reading behaviour in Python so that file decryption is performed beforehand?

Tags: python, encryption, io, pytorch, pickle

I have a machine learning pipeline which reads multiple `pickle` and `torch` files. To protect the models, I want to keep these files **encrypted** in disk and decrypt them during runtime when the file is read by Python.

The codebase is quite large, so rewriting all the I/O bits would be rather tedious and time consuming. Thus, I am looking for a solution that rather overrides the default behaviours and/or works as a drop-in replacement.

To illustrate my goal, I would like this behaviour

```py
import pickle

with open("/encrypted/file.pkl", "rb") as f:
    decrypted_file = pickle.load(f) # pickle.load automatically decrypts the file
```

and also

```py
import torch

decrypted_state_dict = torch.load("encrypted/state/dict.bin") # torch.load automatically decrypts the file
```

Unfortunately, an ad-hoc solution of the type "decrypt everything and save to disk -> run the pipeline -> encrypt again" does not work for me as the pipeline takes hours and in the meantime all the files would be left unprotected.

Also, this behaviour would need to propagate across the entire codebase.

Ideally, the solution would involve the least amount of changes, but ultimately any solution is well received.

I would really appreciate any guidance on how to tackle this problem.